# Selenium to click other div after specific div tag (Specified in Xpath)

Tags: c#, selenium

I needed help in making a function to click a specific div tag. Below is the walkthrough for that.

I have a static div tag which contains

```
<div role="heading" tabindex="-1">...</div>
```

Now right after this div there another which is dynamic

```
<div data-convid="AAQkADE3YTQxZjAyLTVkZTEtNDM3Ni05MjU2LWU0OTc3ODI1MjEwNgAQAP2rdT4x8K5Lo8nEGqTp+QI=" data-time="2017-12-19T13:43:35-05:00" id="_ariaId_447" aria-selected="true" tabindex="-1">...</div>
```

Now in this data-convid, ids are dynamic so I can't specify that in my code to click on specific ids or data-convid. Whenever there is an update or new record. Above div gets populated with new data-convid, ids. Just take it as an email, where whenever you have new email new dynamic div is created. This is similar to that. Now how can I click on the new line which was created?

I was thinking is specifying Xpath for `<div role="heading" tabindex="-1">...</div>` then click first div after that. But don't know how to implement that. Can anyone help me on this?

Please let me know if you guys have any question or concern. Also please do not downgrade or report if this post seems to be misleading or anything else. Please comment I will delete this post.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the work, I've done with Selenium and Awesomium lead me to decide that advanced implementations like this and better are not well suited to these tools, so I took to injecting javascript to do my work and the javascript returns results.

You may find the solution you're looking for, but in the in end you may find, like me, that simply injecting javascript and returning results is the easiest.

**Sample:**

```
IWebDriver driver; // assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelectorAll('div[role=\"heading\"]+div')[0].click();");
```

Comment: Can you share a sample example of how I can do that which is similar to what I am finding which could help in doing that?? Thanks

Comment: @N-ate in my haste I thought you were the OP answering your own question :) My apologies

Comment: You're right, if it is simple and he wants to continue working with Selenium he should use your approach.

Comment: `[0]` means click itself isn't it? I don't know as I never used such. I div need after to `'div[role=\"heading\"` ends

Comment: [0] is an index selector. querySelectorAll returns an array of results.

Comment: +div is what you're looking for. I already updated the sample

Comment: Oh ok thanks I will try this if this works our for me than I will accept your answer. Or if any question I will come back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Would the following XPath be what you are looking for?

```
//div[@role='heading'][@tabindex='-1']/following-sibling::div[@data-convid][1]
```

- Select the first element `[1]`
- with attribute data-convid `[@data-convid]`
- which is a div `::div`
- and is a following sibling `/following-sibling`
- of a div with attribute role = 'heading' and tabindex = '-1' `//div[@role='heading'][@tabindex='-1']`

Answer (score 0):

As per your Question the top most `<div>` tag is as follows :

```
<div role="heading" tabindex="-1">...</div>
```

The above `<div>` tag is followed by another `<div>` tag as follows :

```
<div data-convid="AAQkADE3YTQxZjAyLTVkZTEtNDM3Ni05MjU2LWU0OTc3ODI1MjEwNgAQAP2rdT4x8K5Lo8nEGqTp+QI=" data-time="2017-12-19T13:43:35-05:00" id="_ariaId_447" aria-selected="true" tabindex="-1">...</div>
```

Now the just above `<div>` gets populated with new `data-convid` and the value  of **`data-convid`** attribute is dynamic but you want to `click()` it.

Additionally, the above `<div>` gets populated with new `data-convid`. So to `click()` on the new line which was created, you can construct an **`XPath`** with reference to the top `<div>` with `role` attribute set as **`heading`** which is followed by the `<div>` whose `id` starts with **`_ariaId_`** (as `_ariaId_` looks as a static string) as follows :

```
"//div[@role='heading']//following::div[starts-with(@id, '_ariaId_')]"
```

Incase, **`_ariaId_`** is `dynamic` we can be a bit generic as follows :

```
"//div[@role='heading']//following::div[1]"
```

Perhaps you can get more granular with the parent `<div>` as follows (replace the **...** with **actual_text**) :

```
"//div[@role='heading' and contains(.,'...']//following::div[starts-with(@id, '_ariaId_')]"
OR
"//div[@role='heading' and contains(.,'...']//following::div[1]"
```